# How to make installer of java web application alongwith Apache tomcat and mysql Using Inno Setup

Tags: java, installation, inno-setup, web-deployment, setup-deployment

I have got a requirement to make an installer setup for java web application alongwith  Apache Tomcat and Mysql.I googled and got a free tool called Inno Setup and i managed to make windows
installer setup for .jar file using Launch4J but i am not getting any way how to proceed for the web application..

I need the installer to be like that it insatll JRE ,Apache Tomcat,Mysql and deploy the .war file in the Apache tomcat so that once setup completes installation user can Access the web application from the browser..

Please help me how to achieve this in Inno Setup.
Thanks in advance..